# concatenate a part of two array in one

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, axios

I have two array and I would like to be able to concatener in one but only recovering part of each ...

i use axios with vueJS

```
(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
Nombredejours: 1.5
Task: {id: "52edcb0e-450f-4de7-b70d-b63e047d243d", name: "ABSENCE", description: "", start: "2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z", end: "2099-10-02T00:00:00.000Z", …}
TaskId: "52edcb0e-450f-4de7-b70d-b63e047d243d"
User: {id: "93d04717-1e1e-41f7-8777-b89ac373a900", lastname: "Le Luron", firstname: "David", email: "david.le-luron@polymont.fr", password: "$2a$10$FEZbZz.Ik83iMRGuOd7Lse.udgVZH1daLE/wdSR4Q3csWNY.KOLc6", …}
UserId: "93d04717-1e1e-41f7-8777-b89ac373a900"
UserNumber: 1
createdAt: "2019-10-03T15:18:03.000Z"
end: "2019-10-12T00:00:00.000Z"
heuredebut: "13:00:00"
heurefin: "18:00:00"
id: "03d71d77-3627-4830-9c1e-811a2a58b505"
start: "2019-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"
updatedAt: "2019-10-03T15:18:03.000Z"
__proto__: Object
1:
Nombredejours: 2
```

i would like this :

```
start: "2019-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"
```

and

```
timeStart: "13:00:00"
```

to get that

```
start: '2018-11-19 10:35',
```

Comment: You question doesn't show any arrays, and it's not clear how your expected output is generated from the other data.

Comment: it's good now ?? i have edit

Comment: and i use axios for get data for example :   event.start = '2019-10-9 10:35' but replace the date with the concatenation of the 2 data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let start = "2019-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"
let timeStart = "13:00:00"

let date = new Date(start);
let new_date = date.getFullYear()+'-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-'+date.getDate()+' '+ timeStart.slice(0,5);//prints expected format.

console.log(new_date)
```

Comment: i have this : Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: date is not defined

Comment: @AlexisRouxel Can you try this snippet

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: date is not defined

Comment: for (let eventIndex in myEvents){

                let event = myEvents[eventIndex]

                let start = "2019-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"
                let timeStart = "13:00:00"

                date = new Date(start);
                new_date = date.getFullYear()+'-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-'+date.getDate()+' '+ timeStart.slice(0,5);//prints expected format.

                console.log(new_date)

                event.start = null

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```js
var start = new Date("2019-10-10T00:00:00.000Z").toLocaleString('nl-NL');
console.log(start);
```

Comment: i know this haha, the question is : how i can concatener the variable start: "2019-10-10T00:00:00.000Z" and the variable timeStart: "10:35:00" to obtain this : startFinal: '2019-10-1010:35',